# Connotations of médiocre

Tags: connotation

As with its English cognate, I know the denotation ranges from "poor, disappointing" to "run of the mill, average, nothing to write home about".

In English, the connotation is on the negative end of that spectrum: mediocrity is implicitly opposed to excellence.

> I wouldn't recommend the cupcakes from that bakery. They're mediocre.

What is the connotation in French?

Particularly interested in Canada but ready to accept answers based on other varieties.

Answer (score 3):

In France, the connotation is quite similar to the English: even though it's supposed to be seen as "average", it often has a "somewhat bad" meaning.

On a personal level, I often see a slight change of meaning depending on if you use "médiocre" or "la médiocrité". It seems to me that "la médiocrité" (eg. "la médiocrité du gouvernement Macron") is a stronger shade of bad than "médiocre" (eg. "le gouvernement Macron a obtenu des résultats médiocres"). But this is by personal experience, I wouldn't be able to say if it's a country-wide accepted nuance.

As for your example, although "médiocre" could be used to talk about cupcakes, it's not a common occurrence, we would go for "pas très bons", "pas super", "moyens", "bof". I see "mediocre" generally used to talk about results, and not much else.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful – especially the confinement to results.

Comment: It all depends the level of language. I don't use the word a lot myself, but it could totally be used about cupcakes. note that it can also be used as a noun with the same meaning (rather bad than average)

Answer (score 3):

> In English, the connotation is on the negative end of that spectrum: mediocrity is implicitly opposed to excellence.

Boileau serait bien d'accord : "*Dans l'art dangereux de rimer et d'écrire Il n'est point de degré du médiocre au pire*"

La zone concernée par *le médiocre*, **part** du milieu, du moyen pour s'étendre vers le pire.
C'est ainsi que l'on peut comprendre l'expression *Plus que médiocre* rapportée par Littré et dont le *plus* ne doit donc pas s'entendre méliorativement mais tout au contraire.